# Looking to setup automated notifications for forms in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I've created a form that has a priority drop down.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to be notified via Outlook if the form is submitted somewhere and the drop down has high priority selected.  If it is saved in Sharepoint can a workflow be setup that sees that drop down field?  I don't seem to be able to find anything in the developer tab that would somehow link that field to a notification or alert of some type.  If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate it.  Just trying to automate rather than have to manually rely on others to notify me of high priority tasks.

Comment: Another option would be to somehow flag the critical/high priority option in the drop down but Word seems to only let you do that to the entire selection, the entire dropbox, but not to just one option.

Comment: Which type of dropdown? In Word, it could be a content control (you can use the document-level contentcontrol events for them, but easily detecting a *change* rather than an *exit* may require that you map the control to a custom XML part. It could be a legacy form field, where you have to set the field's properties to run a macro on exit (again, just a change may not be enough). There are a couple of other things it could be.